# PDB debug symbols not loaded during hotload

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to implement hot reloading for a C++ app that loads a DLL dynamically.
When the app runs (in debug mode), it will copy the DLL and associated PDB to an intermediate directory, and load that.
This is so that in subsequent compiles, the original files can be overwritten.
Since DLLs store the path to their PDB in the DLL header, the app patches the DLL header to point to the correct PDB.
To make sure the DLL size remains exactly the same, I only override 1 character of the PDB name.
When compiling the DLL, I set the PDB path to something like the following (using the `/PDBALTPATH` linker flag):

`Z:/NGEN/Stage/Tmp/TheName._.pdb`

Then, when copying the DLL to the Tmp directory, I patch the name to something like:

`Z:/NGEN/Stage/Tmp/TheName.a.pdb`

`Z:/NGEN/Stage/Tmp/TheName.b.pdb`

I verified that the DLLs have the correct patched PDB name after copying, using the `dumpbin` program.

[image: DLL A]

[image: DLL B]

Now, this works fine when I first run the app; the debug symbols are loaded correctly. However, when I rebuild the DLL (in another instance of MSVC) and the app loads the new DLL, MSVC doesn't load the debug symbol of the new DLL.
Instead, I get a message that different versions of the symbols have already been loaded.

[image: Not loaded message]

Why does MSVC not load the PDB associated with the second DLL?

Answer (score 1):

For your reference: [Why does Visual Studio require debugger symbol files to *exactly* match the binary files that they were built with?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimgries/why-does-visual-studio-require-debugger-symbol-files-to-exactly-match-the-binary-files-that-they-were-built-with)

> an internal time-stamp will be different.  But even disregarding that,
> the actual layout of the code could be
> different.

Comment: The PDB file does correspond to the DLL file; they are built together. The only difference being that the DLL header is changed to point to the location where the PDB is ultimately copied. The PDB is not changed.